# Display only one div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a project using Wikipedia API where user can type some name in search and get results from Wikipedia. So i have most of the work but one issue got in my way. When i hover "each-list" div, "show-more" div is displayed from the right side of the parent div which is "each-list" div. Then i hover over "show-more" div which causes appearance of another div called "titleDesc". The problem is when i hover over "show-more" div all "titleDesc" divs displayed whereas i need only one related div to appear.

Javascript code

```
var apiKey = "*****";
var appendApiKeyHeader = function(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Api-Key', apiKey)
};

var name = "Eminem";
var searchRequest = {
  "phrase": name
}

$('#search').click(function() {

  var foundArticle = $("#query").val();

  console.log(foundArticle);

  var wikiUrl = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + foundArticle + '&format=json&callback=wikiCalback';

  // Clear content before AJAX call
  $(".list-container").html("");

  $.ajax({
      url: wikiUrl,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(response) {
          var artList = response[1];
          console.log(artList);
          for (var i = 0; i < artList.length; i++) {
            var title = artList[i];
            console.log("Number" + " " + i + " " + title);
            var titleDesc = response[2][i];
            console.log("Number" + " " + i + " " + titleDesc);
            var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + title;

            $(".list-container").append(
              '<span class = "each-list">' +
              '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank" >' +
              title +
              '</a>' +
              '<div class="show-more">' +

              '<div id="show-more-inner">MORE</div>' +

              '</div>' +

              '</span>' +

              '<div class="titleDesc">' + '<p>' + titleDesc + '</p>' + '</div>'

            );

          } // end of "for" loop

          $('.show-more').hover(

            function() {
              $('.titleDesc').show();
            }

          );
        } // success function end

    }) // ajax function

  return false;

}); // click function

function GetSearchResults() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: appendApiKeyHeader,
    url: "https://api.gettyimages.com/v3/search/images",
    data: searchRequest
  }).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var uri = data.images[0].display_sizes[0].uri;
    $(".images").append('<img src = "' + uri + '" />');
    console.log(data);

  }).fail(function(data, err) {

    console.log(data);

  });
}

GetSearchResults();
```

This code is responsible for display of "titleDesc"

```
  $('.show-more').hover(

    function() {
      $('.titleDesc').show();
    }

  );
```

How to make only **this** div to display?

If you want more details about the [project](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/zBbxyW) feel free to review it.
[image]

Comment: There is no `.titleDesc` in your HTML, Nevermind, i see that it's generated by JS.

Comment: It is added dynamically in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this)                 // the ".show_more" element which triggered the "hover" event
  .parent(".each-list") // the enclosing ".each-list" <span> (*)
  .next(".titleDesc")   // the next sibling with class "titleDesc"
  .show();
```

(*) The generated markup is invalid. The `<span>` element is only allowed to contain other inline elements and no block elements (`<div>`)

Comment: so i need to replace it with div?

Comment: Yes, I would replace the `<span>` with a `<div>` - imho